# DXA Model Extension got stuck in a Pending activation Status

Tags: dxa, add-on

Please find the information below:

1. Installed SDL Tridion 9.1 on a Single Machine following docs.sdl.com guide
2. Installed DXA 2.2 DOTNET
3. DXA 400 Example site imported and published.
4. Installed the Add- On Service as per docs.sdl.com installation guide
5. Uploaded the package "udp-content-dxa-extension-assembly-11.1.0-1061-core" in Add-on service(http://localhost:83/addon/)
6. udp-content-dxa-model-traformation-extension and udp-content-dxa-graphQL-schema-Extension stuck with the status "Pending Activation"

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**DXD loading mechanism** – DXD is loading extensions on service startup. - No support of loading on the fly

After the extensions and configuration have been uploaded to the Add-on Service, the connector/extension is deployed in CM and DXD.

The CM connector will pick up the connector and deploy it on the fly, while the DXD service needs to be restarted to get the connector/extensions deployed.

**Update:**

DXD - Digital Experience Delivery = Content Delivery

Just to clarify to understand.

For your issue, you just need to restart your content service after the add-on service configuration and extension upload.

**Update2:**

[Installation of Add on Service in SDL Tridion Sites 9.1](https://velmuruganarjunan.wordpress.com/2019/09/13/installation-of-add-on-service-in-sdl-tridion-sites-9-1/)

I hope it helps

Comment: What is this DXD Service and what steps needs to be followed to install this DXD Service.  Also it will be a great help if you point me to some document or any path where i can get the step by step approach ... SDL documentation never showing the sequential steps and everything is running in parallel and let to confusion which path to follow

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Hey Rick, I already tried re-starting the session content service. But till now no luck

Comment: then looks like you have some steps or parameter missed in your setup, please refer to blog link for add-on service installation and configuration, updated the answer

Comment: Than Velmurugan, it works now.. The missing part is the environment variable settings what I feel....

Comment: @Velmurugan if i have multiple env how can i setup that in env variable?

Comment: @AbdulQadir: For setting up multiple environments in the same system then you have to pass the environment variables in the command line argument to ./start.ps1 or ./installService.ps1 scripts "-Dcdenvironment=staging"

Comment: I'm having the same issue just missing the addonserviceurl variable