# Issue while installing DXA model extension using SDL Add-On feature

Tags: dxa, dxa2.2, sites-9.1

I am installing the DXA model extension using SDL Add-On feature by following the steps mentioned in [SDL Documentation](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v12/GUID-B0159E6F-E60A-4237-8634-8E5767031744). It's stuck with Status as pending activation. I believe this might be because of something missing(maybe some rights or access to some port). I can't see any error logged into the Event viewer or Add-on service log.

I have already checked a similar TREX question [DXA Model Extension got stuck in a Pending activation Status](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/20877/dxa-model-extension-got-stuck-in-a-pending-activation-status) and verified that I have environment variable configured and I can access content delivery services on my content manager machine.

Can anyone suggest what else I can check?

Comment: Did you restart the content service after the DXA model extension install in the add-on?

Comment: Can you check, Is there any error anything in the content service logs?

Comment: Yes, I restarted the service and no error in my session content service. Wondering if this addon need any configuration? Even I can't see any changes in my Content service..

Comment: Can you also check "\session\extensions\dxa-model-extension.zip" this file downloaded in the extensions folder or not? also ensure content service server has access to add-on service endpoint?

Comment: Thanks @Velmurugan, \session\extensions folder is not available. I can access Add on service from CD server.

Comment: For the record: this question is tagged with `dxa-2.0`, but I assume it is actually DXA 2.1 or 2.2, since you’re using the DXA Model Extension for GraphQL?

Comment: Yes, this is for DXA 2.2. Thanks for pointing this @Rick. I have updated the Tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following steps to troubleshoot.

- Ensure **ContentServiceCapability** registered with the discovery (DXA model extension works without configuration it's mandatory to register the ContentServiceCapability before content service restart, either install the service with auto-register or run the discovery registration and then restart the service, otherwise add-on service doesn't know about the service role)
- Stop the add-on service and restart the session content service to leave it 2 to 3mins, I would expect session content service would go down and also expect to see this below error message in your cd_core.logs

> 2020-05-25 17:00:10,554 ERROR [main] AddonClientFacade - Add-on
>   service specified by URL: 'http://localhost:83/addon' is not up and
>   running but it's mandatory for service to work properly
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Retry limit exceeded.     at
>   com.sdl.delivery.addon.client.api.AddonClientFacade.registerAddonsToDownload(AddonClientFacade.java:160)
>     at
>   com.sdl.delivery.service.WinServiceContainer.main(WinServiceContainer.java:41)
>   Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O
>   error on GET request for "http://localhost:83/addon/api/v1/health":
>   Connection refused: connect; nested

- Also, try to enable DEBUG logs to see what it's going on
- Ensure add-on service URL either passed in the service start-up parameters or the following below environment variables created as per your environment

```
    # Create the system environment variables   
    [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('addonserviceurl','http://localhost:83/addon',[System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)

    [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('cdenvironment','staging',[System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
```

- In the **application.properties** ensure the following properties configured

```
# add-on heartbeat interval. determines how often we should report live status of a service to add-on service.
# default value is every 60000 millis = 1 minute.
addon.heartbeat.interval=60000
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks @Velmurugan. During debugging I saw that issue was indeed because of missing environment variables. I didn't added the cdenvironment variable to "staging" as my CD environment was having both Staging and Live services.